# Does killing the VNC server kill the processes running on it?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, vncserver

I am running a VNC server (vnc4server) on a Ubuntu server.

Does killing the VNC server itself kill the processes on it, such as applications started from VNC sessions?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit but I can't tell precisely what you're asking, so please consider editing it yourself to add more information.

Comment: @bwDraco, thanks for the clarification. I just notice there are various kinds of VNC servers. What I am using is vnc4server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Xvnc, yes, because it contains its own copy of the X server and hosts its own graphical sessions. Terminating the Xvnc server will terminate any applications started in client VNC sessions.

Otherwise, no (unless the VNC server shuts down the X server or sessions on exit), because the VNC server merely interfaces with an existing X server to supply a remote desktop to the client. Klling the VNC server will not kill any programs started in VNC sessions, as the underlying X server and desktop environment are not dependent on the VNC server. Of course, if the server is killed, clients will not be able to access any running sessions.

Comment: Thanks. Just want to make it clear. If I kill the vnc4server (running on a remote ubuntu server), the processes which I started through the vnc4server will not be killed and will still be running. Is that correct? Therefore, a follow-up question, how can I kill those processes correctly? I think through ssh connection, as long as I quit from the ssh connection, all processes I ran are killed, unless I use something like tmux or the processes are database processes.

Comment: Not too sure about this, but user sessions should still be active.

Answer (score -1):

If by "VNC server" in "*running in the VNC server*" you meant a server (operating system) which is (was) running a VNC service then the answer is: no.

Unlike for example the SSH deamon which opens new sessions when users connect (and the processes that users subsequently run become child processes), [VNC server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing#Operation) only shares the screen and allows the control of the machine it is running on, but it is running "side-by-side" with other processes.

Killing VNC server stops the sharing service and would kill VNC client session(s), but does not influence other processes running on the server (operating system).